# Is it possible to write your own REST API in apache airflow?

Tags: rest, airflow

I want to update some of my resource present in database using REST API. Is there a way by which i can create custom REST endpoint in airflow with my own business logic ?

Comment: have been looking for the same too, kindly post if you find some reference

Answer (score 1):

You indeed can extend Airflow, with almost endless possibilities :)

Airflow has something called [Airflow Plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html) which lets you to identify your own custom plugins, that will be loaded into Airflow.
I searched on the web for some plugins that expose REST-API's, and there were some for reference:

- https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin/blob/master/plugins/rest_api_plugin.py
- https://github.com/eBay/airflow-rest-api-plugin
- https://github.com/airflow-plugins/airflow_api_plugin

I bet you can find more if you will search for "AirflowPlugin rest API", or something on that sphere :)

Comment: The problem is, it seems like one can write his own API, with custom authentication, which is not very good, knowing Airflow already has its own mechanism.
I find very difficult to simply add custom endpoints, using airflow's integrated API auth.
Is it even possible?